# Why does a submission form work, but my ajax doesn't?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a button on my chat that will allow someone to print the conversation. So I made the button that runs a PHP script that creates a new file, writes the conversation to file, and also writes the following jQuery.

**jQuery AJAX Call**

```
  function OnBeforeUnLoad () {
            $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: 'deleteFile.php',
               data: {  
                           pageName: ".$pageName."
                     },
               dataType: 'text',
               success: function(data){alert('Good bye 1!');}
            });

            return;
          }
```

**HTML Put into page**

```
<br/><br/><form method="get" action="deleteFile.php"> <input type="submit" value="Close this Window"/> 
             <input type="text" value="'.$pageName.'" name="pageName" style="visibility:hidden"/></form>
```

**deleteFile.php**

```
<?php
$pageName = $_GET['pageName'];
$fullURL = 'PrintPage'.$pageName.'.php';
unlink($fullURL);

echo '<script>window.close();</script>';

?>
```

When the page shows up and I click the "Close this Window" button it does exactly what I want. It deletes the file and closes the window. But I do not get the same results when I close the window (aka OnBeforeUnLoad()). I even tried triggering submit by giving the form an id of deleteFiles and then doing $('#deleteFiles').submit() and it still didn't work.

How do I get the AJAX to work within the OnBeforeUnLoad function?

Comment: What's the `url: ".$pageName."` doing there?

Comment: I have updated my code above... and it is still not working.

Comment: also forgot to mention.. the jQuery call is being added by php so that's why it has url: ".$pageName."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel like a dummy.... After making all those changes... I found out all I needed to do was add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to the header.

Because I was dynamically creating the page in php, I forgot I needed to readd the jQuery.

Always the small things.. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The form calls the data `pageName` but the ajax calls it `url`.

You probably don't want to prefix and suffix the value with `.` characters either.

Comment: In addition, I guess he needs to wrap the value of `pageName/url` with quotations, as I suspect those currently present just escapes a PHP-string.

Comment: isn't the AJAX variable "url" what you want the variable to be called in the PHP file?

Comment: You need to change the `input name="pageName"` to `input name="url"` to make it work.

Comment: @rjg132234 Yes, but in the form it's called `pageName`. When you submit the form it's `$_GET['pageName']`, but when you use AJAX it's `$_GET['url']`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar — The form works but the ajax doesn't. The JS needs to change to `pageName` not the other way around.

Comment: ok I changed pageName in the input to url but it still is not working. Also, I can't edit my question, I want to show you guys more code but I keep getting error pages when I try to edit.

Comment: I even added async: false to the parameters because I read other places that it needs to be false, but it still not working.